# Trouble with file download on iOs Google Chrome

Tags: php, ios, google-chrome

I'm trying to force download a .zip archive using PHP code below:

```
$filePath = BASE_PATH . '/uploads' . $product->mainFile;

header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');                                      
header('Content-Description: Download'); 
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="crazypatterns_' . $product->id . '.zip"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filePath));
```

This code works fine on all browsers and devices... except google chrome on iOs. 
When trying to download archive, on download page - an error occurs: "Cannot determine file size". Archive name is incorect and displays as 'login', and when download this file, filesize is determined incorrectly - 20-30KB, although it's real size is over 10MB.
Screenshot with error occured - https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUpav.jpg .

P.S. $filePath variable is correct, and given archive exists.
Thanks ;)

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the fact that Chrome on iOS currently ignores the Content-Dispostion header?  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=574033